# Easy way to make a static copy of a web app for JSFiddle?

Tags: css, dom, web-applications, jsfiddle

I often have a problem where I'm working on a dynamic web app with tons of front-end or back-end code and there is a CSS problem that just eludes me despite an hour of scratching my head. I know that StackOverflow could solve it in a second, and I'd like to post it, but I either have to

1. Make the app public along with steps to reproduce the state, or
2. Tediously copy out the DOM and assets (CSS) along with the current state.

Neither is very straightforward. Note that the DOM is dynamically generated so "View Source" won't cut it. Similarly, the CSS could be spread out across multiple files and I'd like to just grab it all at once.

Is there an easy way to copy out the DOM and all CSS as a single file so that I can insert it into something like JSFiddle and be on my way?

Comment: Reproduce the problem with the smallest possible amount of code. In 95% of all cases I manage to locate the problem using this method. Even if I have to ask a question I already have all the resources the future answerers might need.

Comment: The smallest amount of code is the DOM + CSS that reproduces the visual bug, which is why I'm asking for a quick way to copy it out. A method that allows me to copy the whole page out would quickly allow cutting out the relevant section.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to get all HTML on the page as-is is to paste this in the address bar:

```
javascript:alert(document.body.outerHTML)
```

You can also use the console, of course, but the above works even in old IE versions and is easier to copy/paste.

I don't think there's a good way to get the CSS at all, but you could try using a jQuery selector or similar to get the URLs:

```
$('link[type="text/css"]')
  .each(function(x, link){
    console.log(link.attributes.href.value)});
```

And downloading and concatenating the CSS.